# How to implement zoom in and out on screen in android?

Tags: android, zooming

I have to implement zoom in and out functionality on particular screen of my app. In it i need to apply this on every item(On vertical lines, image,Dots) which is available on that screen. all things has to zoom when i zoom at any point of screen like Google map.
If any one have any solution, please help me. I am indeed. :(

Comment: Umm.. when you zoom your view, whether your user able to do some activity like clicking on button and filling edit text etc.??

Comment: ya.. right. I have two vertical bars, so i have to make able to move them also in zoom.

Comment: then it is typical as i know. Otherwise if user interaction is not there, then there can be some idea i have to implement.

Comment: Hello, please tell me any way, by which I can apply zoom functionality on entire view of my app screen.

Comment: but if you want user input as without zoom out in zoom in then no idea otherwise you can do with my idea.

Comment: No, i need zoom in and out with user interface.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ["Screen Magnifier"](http://www.androidadb.com/source/eyes-free-read-only/Magnifier/src/com/ideal/magnifier/MagnifierActivity.java.html) code. May this help you.

Or you can do **Reverse Engineering** of current available *"Screen Magnifier App"*.